# Why is Wolverine the only one able to remember "reality" after M-Day?

Tags: marvel, comics, wolverine, house-of-m

After Scarlet Witch changes reality in House of M, Wolverine is seen to be the only person to remember the Earth-616 reality. Why is this so?

Everyone else's memories were changed by Wanda's power, so **how is Wolverine (the only one) able to remember "reality"?**

[image: Screenshot of comic]

Comment: It makes a really nice story.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Wolverine remembered due to a loophole.  Scarlet Witch's altering of the world wasn't solely to create a world where mutants rule, but also, the Scarlet Witch gave many of the X-Men and New Avengers their "heart's desire" (perhaps to keep them content enough to not try to undo things, similar to what was done in a recent Agents of SHIELD storyline on TV).

Wolverine's heart's desire was to remember his past.  Before this, everything prior to the Weapon X program was gone or so hazy and potentially implanted that it couldn't be trusted.  So, when House of M hit, he got his wish and remembered the parts of his life he had previously not known (including his real name)... however, "remember everything" ALSO includes remembering the world as it was before House of M, which everyone else forgot.

As a side note, Wolverine wasn't the only person to remember: Layla Miller also was able to.

Comment: Well, then, the obvious question: how come Layla Miller could remember?

Comment: That would be a separate question, I imagine, but in her case I BELIEVE it was eventually handwaved as part of her unique origin which wasn't explained for a long time after M-Day (and not based on anything created when she debuted).

Comment: Layla Miller didn't remember, she *knows stuff* - a future version of herself came back and told her stuff she needed to know, such as what happened during House of M.

Comment: @sirjonsnow Well, then, the obvious question: how come a future version of Layla Miller could remember?

Comment: She didn't remember, she learned about it after House of M was resolved - I don't know which characters remember what post-HoM, but Layla's *knows stuff* ability came about because she travelled to the future, lived there 10+ years, learned about a lot of the things that happened in the past, then went back and told her younger self about them.  That run of X-Factor was fantastic.